# How much light is needed to quality as possible dark matter candidate?

Tags: visible-light, dark-matter

I know when scientists study dark matter they have already excluded light because of it's negligible effect on the galaxy and of course we are able to observe it directly, I am curious just how much light must the observable universe have in order to abort the idea of dark matter? Also how would we explain the uneven distribution of density of light assuming no need for dark matter? Primordial black hole?

Comment: Photons *are* fairly evenly distributed. Most of the photons flying through the universe are CMB photons.

Comment: Similar one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/451124/

Comment: Perhaps light could in principle account for the mass-energy at global but hard to see it as 1) a stuff that is abundant in galaxies and holds them, 2) isn't dark at all. Cosmology accounts for light indeed. Already.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I know but my scenario assume light is behind the formation of galaxy instead of dark matter

Comment: @Alchimista: yes that question was very inspirational, however I'm looking for what kind of evidence/data is required to confirm whether light is the dark matter.

Comment: I can only repeat my comment with emphasis on point 2. Light is mostly that from CBR / it is accounted for and it isn't enough / light contributes but non sure it can seed any structure. Beside cosmology dark matter was observed by galaxy rotation. There cannot be more light than that emitted within a galaxy. I would say it even escape and does not work as being there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Dark matter must travel at relatively slow velocities. We know this because it can't escape the gravity wells of galaxies. Photons always travel at the speed of light, and thus no amount of them could ever explain the effects of dark matter.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe we can calculate it for the Milky Way. The mass density of the DM in the Milky Way can be taken as $0.4GeV/cm^3=400MeV/cm^3$ Let's assume we have an average energy of gamma-ray $1$ MeV that means in every $cm^3$ in the Milky Way there should be $400$ gamma rays. I think that's a lot.

1- We don't have that kind of a source that produces that kind of energy

2-The energy produced must be constant and doesn't no change with time ( at least for a long period of time)

3- That kind of an energy increase would definitely affect the CMB radiation.

Even this makes sense that's not the whole problem. If you apply the idea to the observable universe then we would have more problems.

When the universe expands matter density drops like $a(t)^3$ but radiation density drops like $a(t)^4$. In this case, we cannot think radiation as a DM candidate. Since the energy density drops faster. And we need that energy to observe the rotation curve in the galaxies etc. Such a fast decrease in density cannot have enough energy to satisfy the above condition and much more.

However in the early universe at one point radiation was much more dominant then DM or matter.

You can calculate the needed radiation energy density by just converting the DM mass to the energy (using the $E=mc^2$) and then you can take the volume of the observable universe and then find the energy density.